# SSL handshake failure on HAProxy load balancer on WSO2 API cluster

Tags: wso2

I configured API-M 2.5.0 cluster with HAproxy Load Balancer by manuals :
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+HAProxy
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Setting+up+a+Cluster

LB doesn't work. I tried to use a self-signed certficate or commercial cert for LB, but when i restart haproxy i have errors in logs:

```
localhost haproxy[95255]: Server as_wso2_com/node1 is DOWN, reason: Layer6 invalid response, info: "SSL handshake failure", check duration: 10ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
```

I think a problem in CA cert or chain. I tried to use CA cert in HAproxy config, didn't help. Any suggestion?

HAproxy config:

```
frontend ft_wrk
    default_backend bk_wrk
    bind wso2.com:80

backend bk_wrk
    balance     roundrobin
    server node1 1.1.1.3:9763
    server node2 1.1.1.4:9763

frontend https-in
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/1.pem
    acl is_mgt hdr_beg(host) -m beg 1.1.1.2
    acl is_wrk hdr_beg(host) -m beg 1.1.1.3

    use_backend mgt_as_wso2_com if is_mgt
    use_backend as_wso2_com if is_wrk
    default_backend as_wso2_com

backend as_wso2_com
    balance roundrobin
    server node1 1.1.1.3:9443 check ssl verify none
    server node2 1.1.1.4:9443 check ssl verify none

backend mgt_as_wso2_com
   server server1 1.1.1.2:9443 check ssl verify none
```

I tried to load balance API with Nginx, but i have errors with SSL cert too. I created question about it:
[SSL certificate error on Nginx load balancer on WSO2 API cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54667838/ssl-certificate-error-on-nginx-load-balancer-on-wso2-api-cluster). I didn't get reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was in mtls on api, i disabled mtls and it works.